# Interoperability between two networks (test and live networks interactions)

Tags: testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Let's assume that I want to test a local contract that interact with a live contract or protocol, can a test network communicate the live one?

For example, If I have an NFT on Ethereum and would like to test the interoperability between my contract and Polygon, can this be done in an ethereum test network?

Thanks